# What is the purpose of lower bounded wildcard in Function.class?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

In Function.class from Java8, we have:

```
default <V> Function<V, R> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(before);
    return (V v) -> apply(before.apply(v));
}
```

Compose accepts:

```
Function<? super V, ? extends T> before
```

Rather than:

```
Function<V, ? extends T> before
```

Is there any plausible situation in which the fact that "V" is lower bounded matters?

Comment: Function interface is uses in cases where you want to encapsulate some code into a method which accepts some value as an input parameter and then returns another value after performing required operations on the input. *The input parameter type and the return type of the method can either be same or different* which makes sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `? super` allows the returned `Function`'s input type (`V`) to be different from the arguments input type.

For example, this compiles with the `? super` version but not the alternate one.

```
Function<Object, String> before = Object::toString;
Function<String, Integer> after = Integer::parseInt;
Function<Integer, Integer> composed = after.compose(before);
```